# C# Singleton with public 'Instance' field instead of property

Tags: c#, singleton

Considering the 'standard' C# implementation of a singleton pattern with type initialisation:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Singleton() { }
}
```

Is there any point in the static property? If the static field is marked as readonly, then surely it cannot be written to from anywhere, including from outside the class. For a more terse implementation, would this work?:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    public static readonly Singleton Instance = new Singleton();
    private Singleton() { }
}
```

It seems fine to me but I've only ever seen the top one used so I wonder if there is anything wrong that I have missed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any point in the static property?

Yes. It hides the *implementation detail* that the value is retrieved from a field in the exact same class. If you expose the field, you're stuck with that implementation forever (assuming you can't later change/rebuild all code referring to it). If you use a property, you could later:

- Change to use `Lazy<T>`
- Use a field within a *nested* class to get potentially lazier initialization if you want to have other static methods in the class
- Use some new and funky scheme yet to be devised

Basically, with a property you've got options for future change. With a field, you haven't.

I used not to think this was a relevant difference, but in Noda Time I've had situations where complex type initialization ordering issues have made it really important that I can control this sort of thing. Where I've exposed a public static readonly field in an earlier version, I've later regretted it :(

A public static readonly field works in terms of still being a singleton - it just gives you less control.

As an aside, you *may* wish to add an empty static constructor to your class. See my articles on [singleton implementations](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) and [`beforefieldinit`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: See option 5 in http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In case of the Singleton pattern it's not very harmful to have a public readonly field rather than just a getter.

The reason the 'standard' implementation is using a getter is to be consistent with the rest of public getters and make you adopt good habits for all the other cases where a getter is more appropriate than a poublic field (for adding functionality without changing the interface for example)

Comment: I dispute the "nothing wrong" part - it limits your options later. See my answer.

Comment: I suppose there are two parts the question - firstly whether it breaks the principle of only ever creating a single instance, and secondly whether it is a good idea even if it does technically work. I think 'nothing wrong' was referring to the first part of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Readonly will mean that it is an instance variable that cant be written to, static is a variable that can be read without instantiating the object. For example you would call them as follows:

```
//Readonly
var readonlySingleton = new singleton();
var result = readnlySingleton.Instance;

//static readonly
var result = singleton.Instance;
```

Comment: You've missed the point of the question, which is between exposing a property or directly exposing a field.